# Get occurrences per month

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So I'm putting up a chart displaying events per months over the last 7 months. I'm getting the last 7 months by using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) like this:

```js
    let dateFrom = [];
    for (var i = 6; i >= 0; i--) {
      dateFrom.push(moment().subtract(i, "months").endOf("month").format("MMMM"));
    }
    console.log(dateFrom);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I have a list of events like this, each with random months:

```
var eventList = [
  { org: "org1", date: "2018-03-07T09:46:45Z" },
  { org: "org1", date: "2018-01-07T09:46:45Z" },
  { org: "org2", date: "2018-02-07T09:46:45Z" },
  { org: "org2", date: "2018-03-07T09:46:45Z" },
  { org: "org3", date: "2017-03-07T09:46:45Z" },
  { org: "org3", date: "2017-11-07T09:46:45Z" }
]
```

And I want to get the occurrences of events per month for each `org`. I imagine the output should kinda be like this (note that any months outside the spectrum of the last seven months should be avoided):

```
let result = {
  "org1": {
    "September": 0
    "October": 0
    "November": 0
    "December": 0
    "January": 1
    "February": 0
    "March": 1
  },
  "org2": ...
}
```

So I guess imagine the setup will be like this:

```
let sevenLatestMonths = [... the months ...]
let events = [{... the events with UTC dates ...}]
let result = {};
```

How do I go about it? I don't even have a clue where to start. 
Greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it, although it's a bit ugly

```js
    let result = {};
    let a = [
              { org: "org1", date: "2018-01-07T09:46:45Z" },
              { org: "org1", date: "2018-01-07T09:46:45Z" },
              { org: "org2", date: "2018-02-07T09:46:45Z" },
              { org: "org2", date: "2018-03-07T09:46:45Z" },
              { org: "org3", date: "2017-03-07T09:46:45Z" },
              { org: "org3", date: "2017-11-07T09:46:45Z" }
      ];
    let months = [
                  "September",
                  "October",
                  "November",
                  "December",
                  "January",
                  "February",
                  "March"
                ];
    let monthsObj = {};
    
    months.map((value) => {
        monthsObj[`${value}`] = 0;
        return monthsObj;
      }
    );

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
     let orgName = a[i].org;

      if (!result[orgName]) {
        result[orgName] = {};
        Object.assign(result[orgName], monthsObj);
      }
      
      months.forEach(month => {
      
        if (moment(a[i].date).format("MMMM") === month) {
          result[a[i].org][month] += 1;
        }
      })
    }

   console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```